# jQuery Ajax call attached to HTML form submission behaves strangely, gets borked without an event.preventDefault() call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a very strange problem. There is this Ajax call that is attached to the submit button of a form. When the form is submitted, the Ajax function gets called and does some checking in the backing ground. This function works.

This is the function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#system-login").submit(function(){
    // event.preventDefault();
    const username = $("#username").val();
    $.ajax({
      headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
      method: 'GET',    
      url: "hashget",
      data: {
        'username': username
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      // global: false;
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("a very bad thing happened");
        console.log("the xhr reponse is --> %o", xhr);
        console.log("the status is --> %o", status);
        console.log("the error is --> %o", xhr.responseText);
      }
    })
    .done(function(res){
      console.log("Heehee");
      console.log("The result is --> %o", res);
      if (!(res["success"])) {
        console.log("this user does not exist");
        $("#baduser").val("true");              
      } 
     })
    .fail(function() {
      console.log("No!!!!");
    })
  });
});
```

Originally, I put in the event.preventDefault() call to check the Ajax response etc. So after all the debugging was done, I masked it out so the form actually gets submitted.

There is where it gets strange. The form gets submitted fine. However the Ajax returns an error in the console. What's even stranger is the "xhr.responseText" is *undefined*. So I have no idea what is triggering the error.

After a lot of trial and error I found that setting `global` switch to false (the second masked line in the code above) suppresses the error.

Could somebody help? Many thanks!

Comment: You would either use ajax to submit your form or the default http request. Mixing it like you do makes not a lot of sense. If you just submit it via http request anyways, the work you do in your ajax call can be done in that request. Or in the other way, if you post it with ajax, the work you do in the http request can also be done in the script handling the ajax call.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't make sense. Still, it should work correctly without errors.

Comment: No. When you submit the form via ajax you make an asynchronous request to the server. While waiting for the response of that request you make the http request, sending the form data to the server and redirecting to the "action" url of your form. I would expect this not to work or show strange/unwanted behavior.

Comment: It does work, as data retrieved by the async call is sent forward to the destination specified by the form.

Comment: Sending the data from your client to the server is **not** the problematic part. The problems are to be expected when you try to process the response in your ajax call. It might work, **but it most certainly will not always work as expected**. E.g. the http request might already have redirected you to another page when the ajax response hits your client and that will most likely always lead to unexpected/unwanted and  **hard to debug behavior**, which is why you should not mix the two.